# How to create a maximized glfw window?

Tags: c++, x11, glfw

Is this even possible?

I am using the [OpenGL version](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/opengl_example/main.cpp)
of [imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui), and one thing is really annoying me,
I can't seem to find a way to create a maximized window *for* imgui.

```
if (!glfwInit())
  ...

GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 800, "window name", nullptr, nullptr);

/* Maximize window here, but how? */
```

I have dissected the glfw code a little bit, and it seems like there is no way to get the native window handle, which would be X11 in my case.

Is there any other way to magically maximize the glfw window after its creation?

Comment: [There is a way to get the native window](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html).

Comment: @Leiaz: Thanks, how couldn't I have seen that... Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any cross-platform function in GLFW to maximize a window but [GLFW provides a way to access the native windows.](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html) The functions are in a different header and macros are used to indicate the window system, so to make the`glfwGetX11Window` function available :

```
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_X11
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_GLX
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

for anybody coming across this question now, there is in fact a way to maximize a GLFW window without requiring access to the native window
`glfwSetWindowAttrib(_Window, GLFW_MAXIMIZED, GLFW_TRUE);`.